# jquery delay problem

Tags: jquery

When a user switches between tabs I'd like it to load the content based on the tab instantly... It works, when you click a tab the new page loads, but you see the old page for about a half a second, before the new one loads, so it looks odd. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks :)

I believe the problem is somehow in the load().hide().fadeIn() but from what i read it should go instantly without any delays... It's odd because it works seamlessly on my localhost, but on hostgator it has a delay when the different tabs are clicked on?

```
if ($('li:first').hasClass('active')) {
$('#populate').load('basic.php').hide().fadeIn('slow');
}

$('li:first').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
return;
}
$('li.advanced').removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
$('#populate').load('basic.php').hide().fadeIn();
}); 

$('li.advanced').click(function() {
if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
return;
}
$('li:first').removeClass('active');
$(this).toggleClass('active');
$('#populate').load('advanced.php').hide().fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since [`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) is asynchronous, it returns immediately when you call it. This is probably what's causing the problem with the old content showing - you're hiding and fading in an old version of the content before the load completes. You can pass `load()` a callback so that the hide/fade run after the load has finshed like so:

```
$('#populate').load('advanced.php', function() {
    $('#populate').hide().fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: +1 Also, one way would be to use `ajax` with the option of `beforeSend`. So some sort of a loading icon would get displayed.

Comment: That's a good point. I think `.load()` causes the browser spinner to spin as it would for a normal page load, but if you want to give more feedback to the user, putting it in `beforeSend` is a nice approach.